# Как написать данную строчку на языке python

Tags: python, pascal

Допустим, есть такая строчка на Паскале:

```
a: array ['A'..'Z'] of integer;
```

Как эта строчка должна быть записана на Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string
d = {i: int() for i in string.ascii_uppercase}
print (d)
```